# Spring Boot Test with CSRF and SpaCsrfTokenRequestHandler - MockMvc api with csrf does not work

Tags: spring-security, junit, csrf, spring-test, mockmvc

I am trying to use Spring Boots suggested SpaCsrfTokenRequestHandler that will use the double submit cookie pattern for CSRF but the MockMvc api with `csrf()` does not seem to support this when it comes to testing. Manually supplying a csrf token value in the cookie and header on request works but ideally the MockMvc api would work with the `csrf()` option.

I am following spring docs here:
[Spring Boot CSRF With SPA Application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript-spa)
[Spring Boot Testing With CSRF](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/csrf.html)

With the SPA App, a double submit cookie is used as the CSRF protection mechanism, where the JS app should return the value held in an "xsrf-token" cookie and pass it in an "x-xsrf-token" header per request.

Generally the approach here:
[Double Submit Cookie Pattern](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#alternative-using-a-double-submit-cookie-pattern)

When I use Spring Security in tests as shown below using the MockMvc `with(csrf().asHeader())`
the token always is said to be invalid.

I am unsure if that is because mockmvc is not binding a value to a header AND a cookie or if this API is not useable for this scenario?

This works:

```java
mockMvc
    .perform(post("/api/some-endpoint")
        .cookie(new Cookie("xsrf-token","abc"))
        .header("x-xsrf-token","abc")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .content("Some body content")
     .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
     .andReturn();
```

This does not:
`org.springframework.security.web.csrf.InvalidCsrfTokenException: Invalid CSRF Token 'J68ItVNNwwdMhD-qLrdkGN8ox2fAk73IO4md1BNIGvIl-IFlQZY8hGp59GRhtAbOG5pQKe0Z6galoInlX-z-7XJxfsoVy7AD' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.`

```java
mockMvc
    .perform(post("/api/some-endpoint")
        .cookie(new Cookie("xsrf-token","abc"))
        .with(csrf().asHeader())
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .content("Some body content")
     .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
     .andReturn();
```

And nor does this:
`org.springframework.security.web.csrf.InvalidCsrfTokenException: Invalid CSRF Token '1SKNwUSrMfPyT9Wp4A1hP8zjY-31exqNdqGvz4avElN50TTQthDp8HOcAZDffu2cgSBVC__UTtTCQnigEJmcquTKczdLtwHg' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.`

```java
mockMvc
    .perform(post("/api/some-endpoint")
        .with(csrf().asHeader())
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .content("Some body content")
     .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
     .andReturn();
```

Comment: this is sanity question since you have not disclosed the code for it, you are properly setting up the mockMvc client as outline here in the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-testing

Comment: and since you have not disclosed your actual implementation this is what it should look like https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript-spa because im not going to do guessing unless we are actually sure that the implementation is sound. Also where are your `DEBUG` enabled logs?